# Disable word break

Tags: hyphenation, text-manipulation

How can I disable word breaks in the whole document? I don't want any of my words broken and hyphenated across 2 lines.

I have tried to use the package:

```
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
```

But then my margin gets weird. This is all my preamble:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\linespread{1.5}
```

And in my main I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\input{z.preamble/preamble.tex}
```

Comment: Weird margins?! Can you show us what you mean by that? Instead, provide code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that the community can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you mean. We don't have access to your `z.preamble/preamble.tex`, which currently makes your code somewhat useless.

Comment: If you disable hyphenation you need to allow something else, either over-stretched white space (use `\sloppy`) or stop justification and use `\raggedright`  Trying to justify both margins while disabling hyphenation can not produce reasonable results.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would you like to convert your comment into an answer? It seems it fixed the problem.

Comment: @samcarter done

Answer (score 5):

If you disable hyphenation you need to allow something else, either over-stretched white space (use `\sloppy`) or stop justification and use `\raggedright`.

Trying to justify both margins while disabling hyphenation can not produce reasonable results.